# JS onclick function

Tags: javascript

If I have a function like:

```
function init() {
  var btn = document.getElementById('sort-btn');
  btn.onclick = btnHandle();
}
```

`btnHandle()` gets executed without clicking the button.
It executes as soon as the page loads.

but if the code is:

```
function init() {
  var btn = document.getElementById('sort-btn');
  btn.onclick = btnHandle;
}
```

it executes normally. 
What is the difference between the two?

Comment: btnHandle will be a function . So to call a function you should add btnHandle();

Comment: Well the difference is simple, in case one, you added `()` to it, forcing it to run. And in option two, you didn't.

Comment: One is function call and second is object assign

Answer (score 1):

When you use `btnHandle()`, function is invoked immediately but with `btnHandle`, you pass a reference to this function which gets executed on the click of button.

Answer (score 1):

`btnHandle` evaluates as the value of a variable.

`btnHandle()` takes the value of a variable, calls it as a function, and evaluates as whatever the function returns.

---

`btn.onclick = btnHandle;` assigns the function to `onclick`.

`btn.onclick = btnHandle();` assigns the return value you get when you call the function to `onclick`.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign a function to onClick, not a value.

In your code:

**btn.onclick = btnHandle();**
btnHandle() will be executed when the page run, and the result will be assigned to onClick.

**btn.onclick = btnHandle;**
btnHanle is a function and it will be called when the button is clicked.